# Как передать динамически получаемую строку другой программе в качестве параметра

Tags: bash

У меня в папке лежат архивы с дампами бд. Мне необходимо получить наиболее свежий архив, и разархивировать его в текущую директорию. У меня не получается передать в `unzip` название файла. Моя команда такая:

```
$ ls -tr | tail -n1 | unzip
```

Здесь первые две команды работают правильно и выдают мне самый "свежий" архив. Но вот как его передать в unzip? Или может какой другой архиватор умеет в пайпы? Я перебрал много вариантов, но ответа на свой вопрос не нашел. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с этим и сможет помочь?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в том каталоге где мне необходимо запустить, любые команды выполняюся с подачи рута

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно обернуть команду в оператор оболочки `$(...)` ([command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)):

```
$ unzip $(ls -tr | tail -n1)
```