# Добавление сегодняшней даты к названию файла при выполнении mv. Cron

Tags: bash, centos, datetime, cron

Например при помощи bash-скрипта будет выполняться команда `$ mv backup.tar backup-[нужно добавить сегодняшнюю дату].tar`
Как это можно сделать? Или где можно про такое почитать?
Скрипт будет запускаться через cron каждые несколько дней и при выполнении в название файла должно вставляться свежее число

Comment: своя функция mv в .bashrc

Comment: `mv backup.tar backup-\`date +%Y.%m.%d\`.tar`

Comment: @PotroNik, [Why is $(...) preferred over \`...\` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как передать динамически получаемую строку другой программе в качестве параметра](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1262648/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: [прочие дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=command+substitution)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67940/110559

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо, после комментария я уже понял, что не сработает

Comment: автору вопроса: ну и учтите, что знаки процента в crontab-е [надо экранировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/670303/178576)